# EWS Java Api search filter ignored

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

```
PropertySet itempropertyset = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
itempropertyset.setRequestedBodyType(BodyType.Text);

ItemView view = new ItemView(10);
view.getOrderBy().add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending);
view.setPropertySet(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Subject, ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived));
SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, searchFilter, view);

service.loadPropertiesForItems(findResults, itempropertyset);
System.out.println("Total number of items found: " + findResults.getTotalCount());

for (Item item : findResults) {
    System.out.println(item.getSubject());
    System.out.println(item.getBody());
}
```

Currently in the application I'm connecting to our exchange, the requirement I have is to read unread mails and get a file attached.

However the search filters are not working, I can change the `Operator` to AND from OR, I can change the `SortDirection` from Ascending to Descending but it makes no difference. My search filter is currently set to unread but it brings back random emails. The ItemView is set to 10 but bringing back 157 emails.

from the println: `Total number of items found: 157`

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?
Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by changing from a `searchFilterCollection` to a `searchFilter` and adding the view, this also fixed the date sorting issue.

```
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults
                        = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false), view);
```